# Hermitian semipositive and Ricci semipositive.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, riemannian-geometry, complex-geometry, curvature, kahler-manifolds

In the paper [Compact Kähler manifolds with Hermitian semipositive anticanonical bundle](http://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/%7Edemailly/manuscripts/dps4.pdf), the authors defined Hermitian positivity of a line bundle:

> Let $X$ be a compact Kähler manifold, a line bundle $L$ is said to be Hermitian semipositive if it can be equipped with a smooth Hermitian metric of semipositive curvature form.

And my question is : wether the condition anticanonical bundle $-K_X$ is Hermitian semipositive is equivalent to the Ricci form of $X$ is semipositive?
If I'm right, semipositive is equivalent to non-negative, so if Hermitian semipositivity of $-K_X$ is equivalent to Ricci semipositivity, then $X$ can be divided into 2 cases: Ricci flat manifolds and Fano(Ricci positive) manifolds, is that right? Any comments are welcome, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your definition, the $-K_X$ is semipositive if you can give $-K_X$ a Hermitian metric $h$ so that the curvature two form of $h$ is semipositive. This $h$ might have nothing to do with the original Kähler metric $g$.

On the other hand, we have the following

> **Theorem (Calabi-Yau)**: Let $(M, \omega)$ be a compact Kähler manifold. Then for any two form $\Omega$ representing the class $\pi c_1(-K_X)$, there is an unique Kähler metric $\bar \omega \in [\omega]$ so that $\operatorname{Ric}(\bar \omega) = \Omega$.

Thus if $-K_X$ is semipositive, one can find a Kähler metric $\bar \omega$ on $M$ with semipositive Ricci form.

It is not true that there is only the Ricci-flat and Fano case. Indeed given a non-negative matrix, you cannot say that either all eigenvalues are zero or all are positive.

For example, $\mathbb P^1 \times T^2$ with the standard Fubini-Study metric on $\mathbb P^1$ and Euclidean metric on $\mathbb T^2$ is not Ricci flat, not Fano, but has a semipositive Ricci curvature.

Comment: Does Ricci-flat means all eigenvalues are zero?

Comment: @Tom Yes. ${}{}{}$

Comment: Can you elabarate it a bit or give a reference?

Comment: Do you mean the last comment? I have added an example. @Tom

Comment: So you mean $-K_X$ semipositive is equivalent to there is a $g$ whose Ricci form is semipositive, but not enough to deduce $X$ must be Ricci-flat or Fano?

Comment: @Tom Yes ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: And $-K_X$ semipositive is not equal to Hermitian zero and Hermitian positive, which separately equals to Ricci-flat and Fano?

Comment: @Tom Yes again.

Comment: It make sense, thanks!